# What happens if a player passes two Zap Orb spaces in one turn?

Tags: mario-party-7

When a player passes a Zap Orbs space set by another player they lose three coins for each space they move past it. What happens if a player passes two Zap Orb spaces in a single turn? Do they start losing 6 coins per space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Zap%20Orb), your guess is correct:

> In both games, if a player passes by another Zap Orb while one is already in effect, the Zap Orbs stack up.